# Find a solution to $tx''+x'+2x = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find a nontrivial (no need to be general) solution to $$tx''(t)+x'(t)+2x(t) = 0$$

W/A spells the solution to some Bessel function. I tried to use the series method so I derive
$$
x = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_nx^n, \quad a_{n+1} = \frac{-2}{(n+1)^2} a_n
$$
well it is not the cleanest solution for this, so I'd like to ask if a explicit solution (non-Bessel function) is available.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x)^n/n!^2 = J_0 (2\sqrt x)$ What do you think that a non-Bessel function exists?

Comment: @Damien while I can see that being a solution, it is a problem from a test and I believe we are required to construct an elementary function. Well if that cannot exist then I'll glad to take Bessel function as solutions.

Comment: If an elementary solution exist for this series, it will mean that the Bessel function has an elementary form